# How to add custom column for max date in Power BI query editor?

Tags: powerbi

I have table with 3 column Id,Date & Value. I want to create two column Max Date & IsLatest.

I try to create Max date column in Query Editor but not able to do it. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group By` with advanced option. Add two new columns, `ALL_ROWS` using the `All Rows` operation and `LAST_DATE` using the `MAX` operation on `Date`. Then expand `Date` and `Value`from the `ALL_ROWS` column. Then add a conditional column with this logic `IF ALL_ROWS.Date = LAST_DATE THEN "Latest" ELSE NULL`. Rename and move columns to desired order. Result:

```
ID  IsLatest    Date        Value   LAST_DATE
1               2019-11-20  10      2019-11-21
1   Latest      2019-11-21  20      2019-11-21
1   Latest      2019-11-21  30      2019-11-21
2               2019-11-18  40      2019-11-19
2   Latest      2019-11-19  50      2019-11-19
2   Latest      2019-11-19  60      2019-11-19
3               2019-11-15  70      2019-11-17
3   Latest      2019-11-17  80      2019-11-17
3   Latest      2019-11-17  90      2019-11-17
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Edit Queries > Home > Group By` and click the `Advanced` button. At the first drop down chose your `ID` column. Next add the aggregations

```
New column name     |        Operation    |      Column
-------------------------------------------------------
Sum Value                     Sum                Value
Max Date                      Max                Date
```

and hit `OK`. Make sure that your `Date` column is from type date (that the max works properly). The `IsLatest` column can you add aferwards by `Add Column > Custom Column` with the following expression:

```
 ="Latest"
```